# Cannot login to MSSQL docker in Gitlab CI for start testing migration

Tags: laravel, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to setup CI/CD for my project. My problem is when Laravel starts the migration this errors occurs:

[image]

In my gitlab-ci file, I tested localhost, 127.0.0.01 and the image name (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server) as Host for DB-Host and MSSQL-Host. None of them works. I don't know it because of a network issue between docker and gitlab or the Dockerfile configuration.

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
# Set the base image for subsequent instructions
FROM php:7.3

# Update packages
RUN apt-get update

# Install PHP and composer dependencies
RUN apt-get install gnupg -qq git wget curl libmcrypt-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev 
libbz2-dev libzip-dev

# Clear out the local repository of retrieved package files
RUN apt-get clean

# Install needed extensions
# Here you can install any other extension that you need during the test and deployment process
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip

# adding custom MS repository
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql- 
release.list
# install SQL Server drivers
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev msodbcsql17
RUN pecl install sqlsrv \
&& docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv

RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv \
&& docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv
RUN echo "extension= pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
RUN echo "extension= sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
# Install Composer
RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install Laravel Envoy
RUN composer global require "laravel/envoy=~1.0"
```

**.gitlab-ci.yaml:**

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/mycompany/myRegisteryContainer

services:
  - mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

variables:
  MSSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
  MSSQL_PID: Developer
  ACCEPT_EULA: Y
  SA_PASSWORD: myStrongPassword
  DB_CONNECTION: sqlsrv
  DB_PORT: 1433
  DB_HOST : 127.0.0.1
  DB_DATABASE: dbname
  DB_USERNAME: dbuser
  DB_PASSWORD: dbpassword

stages:
  - test
  - deploy-prod

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    - composer install
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate
    - vendor/bin/phpunit

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy-prod
  script:
    - "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )"
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

    - ~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run deploy-prod --commit="$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://api.mywebsite.com
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services) the automagic default service names created for you should be `mcr.microsoft.com__mssql__server` and `mcr.microsoft.com-mssql-server` (although I did not test and I have a doubt about how periods are really handled here).

You might want to [create a service alias](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-services) in this case to keep it shorter, under control and easier.

In `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
services:
  - name: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    alias: mssql
```

You can then use `mssql` as your server name to access the db. If the variables you have in your ci files are correctly doing their job, you should just have to set

```
variables:
  MSSQL_HOST: mssql
  # [...]
  DB_HOST: mssql
```